# Real time adjustments of split pane Java

Tags: java, swing, split, pane, adjustment

I just created a simple split pane which has 2 textpanes on both the sides. It looks good, but when I try to move it left or right, it doesn't adjust the width in real time rather it shows a faint line while moving. When I release the mouse then the adjustments are made.

Is there any technique in java that I can adjust the widths in real time rather then the faint line moving and adjusting when mouse is released?

How I want 
[image: Required]

How It is 
[image: How it is]

See in the first one, the frame is adjusting the positions of the things in realtime(responsive).
But in my window the splitpane is actually creating a virtual one and when i release it then it is resizing the things.

How do I set it like the first one which adjust the things while moving the divider in realtime(responsive)?

Comment: (1-) 1) You have been asked before to post an [mre] with your questions. 2) *Is there any technique in java* yes. Read the JSplitPane API BEFORE posting a question. The method to use should be obvious.

Comment: @camickr, I have added a gif to show what i want and what i got. Please check that.

Comment: I understand what you want. My answer is still the same.  `Read the JSplitPane API`. If you did that a week ago you would have your answer. A good place to start is with all the "setter" methods. You can't learn to program if you don't learn to read the API.

Comment: @camickr, Thanks I found out a method for that. Actually I'm not a Doc reader, I just learn from YT.

Comment: *Actually I'm not a Doc reader, I just learn from YT.* - and that was my point. The FIRST place to look is the API! You problem could have been solved in a couple of minutes instead of several days.

Comment: @camickr, thank you for your patience and support 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method `setContinuousLayout(boolean newContinuousLayout)`
Use it like this

```java
splitPane.setContinuousLayout(true);
```